# importing data into R with unique values across 2 excel files

Tags: r

I have the following excel file;

```
excel1
    KeyID number SR WE VD_SDGD ATM   NA    EUR  A   P NU
1:  253422 1114  0  1 78271 1008     3    9.87 NONE 0  0
2:  253422 1114  0  1 78271  301     3    2.97 NONE 0  0
3:  253422 1114  0  1 78271  300     5    4.95 NONE 0  0
4:  253422 1114  0  1 78271  304     1    0.99 NONE 0  0
5:  253422 1114  0  1 78271 2060     8   15.92 NONE 0  0
6:  253422 1114  0  1 78271  615     2    3.98 NONE 0  0
```

The file is rather big and I would like to only import a certain subset of rows from this datafile based on another excel file. (The file exce2 can be imported into R as it is significantly smaller than excel1)

excel2

```
          A           B            C         SR WE  VD_SDGD  ATM
   Muffin         Company name1  Product1    0   1  78271    1008  
Choc chip Muffin  Company name2  Product1    0   1  36300    4632
   Muffin         Company name2  Product2    0   1  78271    301
```

What I am trying to do is to import excel1 into R so that I only keep the Muffin results using excel2.

i.e.
Import all rows from excel1 into R through matching with exact colname identifyer (SR,WE,VD_SDGD, ATM) from excel2 so that I have a dataframe with all the excel1 columns and I know that only the Muffin results will be imported.

Comment: For what I understand, take a look at `?merge`. Maybe `merge(excel1, excel2)`, see also the `by` and `all.*` arguments in the help page.

Comment: You need to use an external database.